# helm - run pods and dependencies with a predefined flow order

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jobs

I am using K8S with helm.

I need to run pods and dependencies with a predefined flow order.

How can I create helm dependencies that run the pod only once (i.e - populate database for the first time), and exits after first success?

Also, if I have several pods, and I want to run the pod only on certain conditions occurs and after creating a pod.

Need to build 2 pods, as is described as following:

I have a database.

**1st step** is to create the database.

**2nd step** is to populate the db.

Once I populate the db, this job need to finish.

**3rd step** is another pod (not the db pod) that uses that database, and always in listen mode (never stops).

Can I define in which order the dependencies are running (and not always parallel).

What I see for `helm create` command that there are templates for deployment.yaml and service.yaml, and maybe pod.yaml is better choice?

What are the best charts types for this scenario?

Also, need the to know what is the chart hierarchy.

i.e: when having a chart of type: listener, and one pod for database creation, and one pod for the database population (that is deleted when finished), I may have a chart tree hierarchy that explain the flow.

[image]

The main chart use the populated data (after all the sub-charts and templates are run properly - BTW, can I have several templates for same chart?).

What is the correct tree flow

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fixed order with which helm with create resources, which you cannot influence apart from [hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/).

Helm hooks can cause more problems than they solve, in my experience. This is because most often they actually rely on resources which are only available after the hooks are done. For example, configmaps, secrets and service accounts / rolebindings. Leading you to move more and more things into the hook lifecycle, which isn't idiomatic IMO. It also leaves them dangling when uninstalling a release.

I tend to use jobs and init containers that blocks until the jobs are done.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    name: mysql
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mysql
      image: mysql
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: migration
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-for-db
          image: bitnami/kubectl
          args:
            - wait
            - pod/mysql
            - --for=condition=ready
            - --timeout=120s
      containers:
        - name: migration
          image: myapp
          args: [--migrate]
      restartPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-for-migration
          image: bitnami/kubectl
          args:
            - wait
            - job/migration
            - --for=condition=complete
            - --timeout=120s
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myapp
          args: [--server]
```

Moving the migration into its own job, is beneficial if you want to scale your application horizontally. Your migration need to run only 1 time. So it doesn't make sense to run it for each deployed replica.

Also, in case a pod crashes and restarts, the migration doest need to run again. So having it in a separate one time job, makes sense.

The main chart structure would look like this.

```
.
├── Chart.lock
├── charts
│   └── mysql-8.8.26.tgz
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── deployment.yaml    # waits for db migration job
│   └── migration-job.yaml # waits for mysql statefulset master pod
└── values.yaml
```

Comment: If I have mysql provided by bitmani. When should the image first declare and loaded - in the  deployment template, or in the main chart or in my chart that do the population (It is a code in golang that do the populate - I do not want to change code for that).

How can I ensure the database is created and only after that I should run some code to populate data.
The same image that do the population of db is also listen to db (with some other kind of parameters). Basics - the by the number of hook-weight is enough to set the running order of the pods?

Comment: @Eitan, make the msql chart a subchart of yours. Then use a init container on your app deployment to block until the DB is ready. You could wait for some master pod to be ready instead of a job completion like in this example. However, if you want to scale, you should move your database population (aka migration) into a dedicated job. It can be the same image as your application, maybe just started with a different flag. That way, if you scale your app, you still run only 1 time the migration instead of multiple times. You ask about hook weight, I think hooks are not the right thing for this.

Comment: @Eitan, I have edited my example to showcase this a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much. What the hierarchy should be (in your answer would be fine). Main chart -> dependencies of pod and job, and in sub charts one for the pod, and one for the job? On main -  there is the main listener, that is up after all dependencies are up (how). For the job - create only one replica? Can I commit the docker while.

Comment: @Eitan, sorry,  I don't really understand the question.  The migration job waits for the DB pod of the subchart. And your own deployment waits for the job to finish, before starting.

Comment: I have edited my original post for clarification - See the tree. Just a tree flow explanation would be great! You mentioned pod, and job. Can you show the flow tree from main chart until the last sub chart, as I did, please. In each template - what is the type criteria, and which sub chart? Thanks.

Comment: @Eitan, I have addded an example chart layout.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know much about bitnami/kubectl - is it a well known technique to do wait for the previous pod/element to complete/ready? I don't know what to write in pod yaml (for mysql), since I put that on chart dependencies: dependencies section:
  - name: mysql
    version: 8.8.23
    repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"

Comment: @Eitan, in my example, I also used as dependecy from bitnami. Thats why its a tgz archive. You need to check what will be the name of the mysql pod when its deployed and use that in your wait command.

Comment: for deployment section the image is from bitnami repository, the image repository loaded is: bitnami/mysql and the tag: 8.0.28-debian-10-r0. on mysql.yaml file: the image is mysql (not bitnami/mysql). I cannot supply the tag - because it was pulled automatically from latest version of 8.2.23 (also after running: helm add repo bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami), so mysql and bitnami/mysql are different.

Comment: @Eitan, at the end it doesnt matter where you get your mysql from. What is important is to find out what will be the name of the master pod of the stateful set and wait until its ready.

Comment: OK. So, how can I cause that the pod will be the same one as the dependency (in dependency section in chart.yaml) - it create another pod for that, and I want to use the same pod.

Comment: Also - I see the error: The MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable is empty or not set. So I need to pass the root password to mysql. 
How can I declare that in the pod yaml file itself?

Comment: @TheFool I believe this is a good idea, but your example won't work because of ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100. As soon as the job is deleted (100 seconds after completed/failed status) kubectl wait job/migration will not evert work again (the command fails) and your app will not start.

Comment: @MikhailNaletov, yes, that's right. Its not super solid and you need to add a few things to make it work. If you can get with another way, you probably should.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using helm hooks and K8s Jobs, below is defining the same setup for Rails applications.

The first step, define a k8s job to create and populate the db

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-db-prepare
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-1"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
  labels:
    app: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "my-chart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  backoffLimit: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-db-prepare
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        command: ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
        args: ["rake", "db:extensions", "db:migrate", "db:seed"]
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-configmap
        - secretRef:
            name: {{ if .Values.existingSecret }}{{ .Values.existingSecret }}{{- else }}{{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-secrets{{- end }}
      initContainers:
      - name: init-wait-for-dependencies
        image: wshihadeh/wait_for:v1.2
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        command: ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
        args: ["wait_for_tcp", "postgress:DATABASE_HOST:DATABASE_PORT"]
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-configmap
        - secretRef:
            name: {{ if .Values.existingSecret }}{{ .Values.existingSecret }}{{- else }}{{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-secrets{{- end }}
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{ .Values.imagePullSecretName }}
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Note the following :
1- The Job definitions have helm hooks to run on each deployment and to be the first task

```
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-1"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
```

2- the container command, will take care of preparing the db

```
command: ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
args: ["rake", "db:extensions", "db:migrate", "db:seed"]
```

3- The job will not start until the db-connection is up (this is achieved via initContainers)

```
args: ["wait_for_tcp", "postgress:DATABASE_HOST:DATABASE_PORT"]
```

the second step is to define the application deployment object. This can be a regular deployment object (make sure that you don't use helm hooks ) example :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-web
  annotations:
    checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum  }}
    checksum/secret: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secrets.yaml") . | sha256sum  }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "my-chart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.webReplicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum  }}
        checksum/secret: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secrets.yaml") . | sha256sum  }}
      labels:
        app: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
        service: web
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{ .Values.imagePullSecretName }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-web
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
          args: ["web"]
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: {{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-configmap
          - secretRef:
              name: {{ if .Values.existingSecret }}{{ .Values.existingSecret }}{{- else }}{{ template "my-chart.name" . }}-secrets{{- end }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
      restartPolicy: {{ .Values.restartPolicy  }}
    {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly, you want to build a dependency chain in your deployment strategy to ensure certain things are prepared before any of your applications starts. in your case, you want a deployed and pre-populated database, before your app starts.

I propose to not build a dependency chain like this, because it makes things complicated in your deployment pipeline and prevents proper scaling of your deployment processes if you start to deploy more than a couple apps in the future. in highly dynamic environments like kubernetes, every deployment should be able to check the prerequisites it needs to start on its own without depending on a order of deployments.

this can be achieved with a combination of `initContainers` and `probes`. both can be specified per deployment to prevent it from failing if certain prerequisites are not met and/or to fullfill certain prerequisites before a service starts routing traffic to your deployment (in your case the database).

*in short*:

- to populate a database volume before the database starts, use an `initContainer`
- to let the database serve traffic after its initialization and prepopulation, define `probes` to check for these conditions. your database will only start to serve traffic after its `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` has succeeded. if it needs extra time, protect the pod from beeing terminated with a `startupProbe`.
- to ensure the deployment of your app does not start and fail before the database is ready, use an `initContainer` to check if the database is ready to serve traffic before your app starts.

check out

- https://12factor.net/ (general guideline for dynamic systems)
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

for more information.